# Laravel Eloquent Model::find doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

This don't work:

```
$object = Model::find($id);
```

This works:

```
$object = Model::where('id', '=', $id)->first();
```

It doesn't make sense. Am I missing something?
I'm using Laravel 5.2.36.

Comment: What is the error from `$object = Model::find($id);`

Comment: You can try $object = Namespace\Model::find($id);

Comment: Let us know when you figure it out, Model::find() does internally exactly what the working code does

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo no, Model::find() searches the primary key field, no necessarily the id field.

Comment: that's true, I just assumed that id is the primary key

Comment: There is no error, Model::find($id) returns null.
Is not a namespace issue. Using \Namespace\Model::find($id) I got the same behavior.
Yes, id is the primary key.

Answer (score 3):

`id` needs to be a primary key, see:
https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_find

Comment: I'm sorry folks. I'm using soft deletes and the record was deleted. The find method do not returns deleted entities, the QueryBuilder (where) does.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I sorted out it, using the function `intval()` to transform `$id` to an `integer` value:

```
$id = intval($id);
$object = Model::find($id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public $primaryKey  = 'id';
```

make it a primary key in your model file or you can use

```
Model::firstOrNew(['id' => $id]);
```

but here id should be a fillable property in the model. for example

```
protected $fillable = ['id'];
```