# Laravel Model::find($id) doesn't filter results

Tags: laravel, datatable, eloquent, laravel-migrations, yajra-datatable

I'm trying to edit a column of datatable to show informations in my index view table.

This is my controller's method that I call throught Ajax in the view:

```
public function getField(){

       // Current User
        $user_id = \Auth::user()->id;
        $users = User::find($user_id)->users();
        return Datatables::of($users )
          ->editColumn('id', '<a href="'.url('users').'/{{$id}}/edit">Edit</a>')
          ->editColumn('fields_id', function($users) {
             $mystring = '';
             $fields_id_array = json_decode($users->fields_id);
             foreach($fields_id_array as $f_id){         

                /* this works */  
                // $mystring  .=  Fields::where('id', '=', $f_id) -> pluck('field_name');

                /* this doesn't work */  
                $mystring  .=  Fields::find($f_id) -> pluck('field_name');
             }
             return $mystring;
          })
          ->rawColumns(['id'])
          ->make(true);
      }
```

The field 'fields_id' in users table is a JSON field like this: ['1','2','5'] and these refers to the id's of another table: 'Fields'.

I have already read this [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37719932/laravel-eloquent-modelfind-doesnt-work) but I think my db table is it ok because increments are primary-key equivalent in [Laravel migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations).

This is my migration for the table 'fields':

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
        Schema::create('fields', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->string('code')->unique();
            $table->string('param1');
            $table->string('param3')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: are you using soft deletes? The query builder where also returns (finds) "soft deleted" entries, where as find does not include those.
Also, what type is your $az_id variable (and what is it's value)?

Comment: No I'm not using soft deletes. 
I forgot to add that find($az_id) return to me all the records of 'Fields' table.

Comment: I'm sorry. $az_id is wrong. The correct name is $f_id and it is an integer.

Comment: hmm... what version of laravel are you using? did you try to check what you get back if you try to run the two statements in "tinker" mode?

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5.4 version. I don't know what is it 'tinker' mode but if I try this, outside of the loop: Fields::find(1) -> pluck('field_name'); I get back this [''Name1","Name2", ... "NameN"]

Answer (score 1):

a wild guess here, based on your last comment...

try this inside you loop

```
$mystring  .=  Fields::find(intval($f_id))->pluck('field_name');
```

I've added the intval() function arround your `$f_id` since you said you said they are in this format ['1','2','5']. that is an array of strings (that should be cast to integers if you plan to use them with `find()` function.

Comment: I have tried this: $mystring  .=  Fields::find(intval($f_id))->pluck('field_name'); but doesn't work.  I can do it also with this:   $fields_id_array = json_decode($user->fields_id);    $fields_array = Fields::whereIn('id',$fields_id_array)->pluck('field_name')->toArray(); and it works but I can't understand why the find does not work

Comment: and if you dd($fields_id_array); just before the loop?
because like you said... if you call Fields::find(1) -> pluck('field_name'); you do get back the array of what you want, that is why i'm thinking the problem is with the value you pass as the argument

Comment: I can't call dd() but print_r($fields_id_array) returns this: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 ) In this case my loop get out twice all the records :  ["Name1","Name2","Name3"] ["Name1","Name2","Name3"]

Comment: I add another detail to question. If I call the method getKeyName(); in this way: (new Fields)->getKeyName(); it get out the correct key 'id'.

Comment: sorry, i ran out of ideas to try... just to check i understand the problem correctly... when you run the $mystring  .=  Fields::where('id', '=', $f_id) -> pluck('field_name'); inside the loop, you get the results back correctly and if you run $mystring  .=  Fields::find($f_id) -> pluck('field_name');
then you get nothing? Also as i wrote this, have you tried printing (var_dump) the result you are trying to append to $mystring (in case that is an array that could be causing some issues)

Comment: In the first case I get out the correct results instead with $mystring .= Fields::find($f_id) -> pluck('field_name'); I get out all the records so many times how many are the loops. Find() doesn't filter results and return the same data as Fields::all() -> pluck('field_name')